# Modify Nested_Field before adding association Cocoon

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cocoon-gem

After the user submits the form, but before the association is added, is it possible to modify the nested field during this time?

For example my nested fields may look like:

```
<div class='nested-fields'>
   <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :count %>
      <%= f.number_field :count %>
   </div>
   <%= link_to_remove_association "remove section", f %>
</div>
```

Say I want to multiply count x 2 before adding the association (after user submits form). Is this possible?

Or a more complex example, I might want to convert the integer to a string then save the association.

link to issue: https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon/issues/361 (i was told to post on SO)

Comment: I _suggested_ you to ask this here, because it is not a cocoon issue, and other people can help you quicker than I can. There are a lot of different ways to achieve this. Obviously this is not your real problem, but a similar example. For me it sounds counter-intuitive that a value is changed before saving, so when the user then wants to edit the item, while you do the reverse operation before showing it back to the user? So a bit more background might give a better/more appropriate solution. Also converting to string will be automatic if the database column is a string.

Comment: @nathanvda Thanks for the answer. I also posted the link on the issue as you suggested :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can modify you permit params:

```
def some_params
  params.require(:some).permit(:count).tap do |white_list|
    white_list[:count] = 2 * params[:some][:count].to_i
  end
end
```